# deny file request and redirect to .php page using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, directory

I'm working with wordpress and I am using .htaccess, but I don't really understand its functionality.

The scenario is the following:
When user tries to reach a file from upload directory (example:  `http://[localhost]/wordpress/uploads/video.mp4`) he is redirected to a php page which decides if the user has a permission to download/view the file or not (for example, redirecting to the following: `http://[localhost]/wordpress/serve.php?filename=video.mp4`).

Does anyone knows what should I do with the .htaccess?

In which directory should the .htaccess file be placed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your WordPress root `.htaccess` file for this, or you can create one in the uploads directory. I'd recommend sticking to the file you're already using for WordPress.

**`/wordpress/.htaccess` amended content**

```
RewriteBase /wordpress/
# ^ your base should already be set - if it hasn't, put this just under RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^uploads\/(.*) serve.php?filename=$1 [R,L]
```

**Note:** If you do not want to redirect, you can still disguise it under the actual file name, and it will still return the PHP response. You can do this by removing the `R` flag. (This will keep the originally-requested URL in the address bar.)

---

**EDIT:** based on your comment, and revealing where your `.htaccess` file resides, try the following:

```
RewriteBase /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /wp-content/themes/fun&share/serve.php?filename=$1 [R,L]
```

---

**EDIT 2:** My apologies, I did not account for the `RewriteBase`. Please see the code below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) ../themes/fun&share/serve.php?filename=$1 [R,L]
```

This `.htaccess` file **must** be placed in your `uploads folder`.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mike, but it isn't working...it shows me internal error :/

Comment: Please see my edited code. If that still fails, please check your Apache error logs. There should be more detail in there.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^uploads\/(.*) serve.php?filename=$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
This is the code I'm using
I think the probllem is in the directories (my .htaccess is in /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/ and serve.php is in /wordpress/wp-content/themes/fun&share/serve.php)
Any other suggestions?

Comment: The code I sampled for you should belong in your root htaccess, as it says. I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Mike, I changed the code but I still get the file when I type the URL. It doesn't redirect me. Anyway, thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Please see my revised code (Edit 2). This should be working now. Please make sure your file is in the correct place.

Comment: Now, I need to redirect files with .pdf and .mp4 extensions

Comment: The rule should work with all files. Hence the `(.*)` - that will capture everything, the condition having checked to see if the file exists.

Comment: If this answer helped you, and it is now working, please mark it as accepted so that others can learn too.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you very much. Now, I have one more queston. When I try to access the video i get message: Forbidden Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /C:/wamp/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/fun&share/serve.php on this server. Why I get this message?

Comment: Not quite sure - you may need to open a new question for that.

Comment: I am new here and I don't know how it is functioning :) Is it okay now? And one more thing. I asked the same question twice (the one that you told me to ask separately as new question) twice but nobody has answered me. Do you know why??

Comment: Oh I see - yeah, it is. I'll check your other question now. I hadn't seen it before.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these rules to an htaccess file in your `/wordpress/uploads` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/serve.php?filename=$1 [L]
```